# Running php from cmd: relative paths issue

Tags: php, windows, cmd

I am currently testing some code in cmd, and I'm experiencing some problems with relative paths.

[image: pic]

It is clearly visible that the path is set correctly, furthermore it works as expected under http protocol. I assume there's something that's blocking relative paths in cmd, because if I replace that with an absolute path the file gets included. This however is not efficient as filesystems may change and the use of relative paths is a must. I'm really bad with OS stuff so I guess I shouldn't be making any more assumptions. Thanks!

**EDIT**: Mind = Blown

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Basics:**

When called from HTTP the working directory of `index.php` is `C:\xampp\htdocs\actualframework\public\` when called from command line (in your example) it is `C:\xampp\php`. So the script tries to include `C:\xampp\Framework/class/routers/System.php` which isn't there.

You need to utilize the `__DIR__` constant in order to make the require command working independently from where `index.php` was called:

```
require(__DIR__ . "/../Framework/class/routers/System.php");
```

`__DIR__` points to the directory where the source file is located which is using the `__DIR__` constant, in your example: `C:\xampp\htdocs\actualframework\public\`

---

**Using `include_path`**

Another good idea is to utilize the `include_path` directive in order to make the real location of a library file transparent to the application. This will give you more freedom when you once change the directory layout. `include_path` is a configuration value that can be set in `php.ini` or in scripts and contains a list od directories where php should look if you pass relative paths to `require` or `include` as well as some functions like `file_get_contents()`, `fopen()`, ...

Configure the include path on top of your `index.php` (or in a separate `bootstrap.php` which gets included):

```
ini_set('include_path', implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    __DIR__ . '/../Framework/class',
    __DIR__ . '/../Framework/interface',
    // add the existing value at the end
    ini_get('include_path')
)));
```

Now you can use paths like this to require classes:

```
require_once 'System.php';
require_once 'routers/Foo.php';
```

**Autoloading**

Since PHP5 there is a feature called [`autoloading`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) which eases the including of classes. Autoloading basically provides the ability to define a hook function which gets called every time a class is accessed which has not been defined before. Imagine you have the following files:

*lib/Person.php*

```
<?php

class Person {

    ... some code
}
```

*index.php*

```
<?php

$hek2mgl = new Person();
```

Normally this code will trigger an error because `Person` is accessed without including `lib/Person.php` before. This is the point where autoloading can be used. Lets see how a simple autoload method can look like in this (simple example):

```
function autoload($classname) {
    $path = __DIR__ . "/lib/$classname.php";
    if(file_exists($path)) {
        require_once $path;
    }
}
```

You need to reqister the autoloader using `spl_autoload_register()`. `index.php` can look like this:

```
<?php

// define simple autoloader for project
function autoload($classname) {
    $path = __DIR__ . "/lib/$classname.php";
    if(file_exists($path)) {
        require_once $path;
    }
}

// register autoloader
spl_autoload_register('autoload');

// will work now
$hek2mgl = new Person();
```

If you ask me, autoloading is one of the coolest things in PHP5. You can refine the autoload method in order to work with the `include_path` directive. Doing so it gets easy to work with a couple of libraries without taking care about where they are physically stored in filesystem. You may give my [`Jm_Autloader`](https://github.com/metashock/Jm_Autoloader) a try, the code is on github and you can install it using PEAR or composer.

Answer (score 4):

As @hek2mgl points out, it has to do with the current working directory being wrong.

In your case the working directory is `c:/xampp/php/` but it should be `c:/xampp/htdocs/actualframework/public/`.
There's at least two solutions to fix this, the most obvious one being changing the working directory on the command line:

```
cd c:/xampp/htdocs/actualframework/public/
c:/xampp/php/php.exe index.php
```

Alternatively you can set the current working directory from your PHP script by adding the following into your `index.php` before you try to `include/require` anything:

```
chdir(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```